# Elastic Beanstalk Degraded error not showing any details with Laravel install

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently uploading a Laravel package to Elastic Beanstalk and I am receiving a "Degraded" error with no details.  Here is what I've done.
When I upload the package status is Ok when I go to the url provided by EB I get a "forbidden" message on my browser.
This is to be expected since the actual path for Laravel is `/public`.

I then go to `Configuration`: `Software` then I modify `Document root to /public` this then gives me a `Degraded error`under Health Degraded Causes there are no errors.  I've also followed AWS way of enabling the enhanced monitoring and it still doesn't show anything.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.  The problem was that I was manually compressing my directory with .zip 
According to AWS Documentation it should be done like so:

```
~/myapp$ zip ../myapp.zip -r * .[^.]*
```

More details found here:
[creating a source bundle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html)